# How to redirect to 301 instead of 302 in Magento 1.9.2.4?

Tags: admin, magento1.9.2.4

How to redirect to 301 instead of 302,
My Magento site contains 302 redirects and its effects to SEO.

So I want to do a permanent redirect (301).

My Magento website converted HTTP to HTTPS and the problem is when browsing with "HTTP" first it 302 then 200.

Its fine to browse URL with "https" it shows 200

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this in the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi @ Shorabh, I have already  added that code in the .htaccess file  in the  root folder but it showing 302 instead of 301

Comment: Hi @ Shorabh, Could you please help me?

Comment: Have You access virtual host server ?

Comment: Hi @ Shorabh, I am using Amazon Linux server

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/ Review this plz